# Create new Object1 and create new Object2 if exists, and then create relationship

Tags: core-data, if-statement, save, relationship, nsmanagedobject

In my data model I have:

```
Object2<-->>Object1
```

Every time a button is pressed I'm creating new Object1's, but my code is currently also creating Object2's on each save. I'm trying to create a check if Object2 exists then don't create it, but if it doesn't exist then create it. After the check, I'm then trying to create a relationship between Object2 (either created or existing) and Object1 and save it. I have the following in my IBAction:

```
    - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    //create Object1
        Object1 *newObject1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Object1"
                                                                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        [newObject1 setValue:self.UILabel.text forKey:@"object1Name"];

    //check if Object2 exists and if it doesn't create new object
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                       entityForName:@"Object2" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

         Object2 *newObject2;
        if (newObject2 == nil)
        {
            newObject2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Object2"
                                                                        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            [newObject2 setValue:self.UILabel2.text forKey:@"object2Name"];
            newObject2.object2Name = self.UILabel2.text;
        }

 //create relationship from Object1 to Object2        
        newObject1.toObject2 = newObject2;   

        NSError *anyError = nil;
        BOOL savedSuccessfully = [self.managedObjectContext save:&anyError];
        if (!savedSuccessfully) {

        }

    }
```

Currently this is continuing to create Object2's with every save. How would I prevent duplicates of Object2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the fetch request, which is correct (though it may require a predicate), but you are never executing it. Executing the fetch will return an array which you need to check (to see if it contains anything) and extract any existing object 2 from there.

```
NSArray *items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:fillInErrorHere...];

if (items.count == 1) {
    newObject2 = items[0];
}
```